# Best practices to work Sqoop, HDFS and Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have to use `sqoop` to import all tables from a mysql database to `hdfs` and to `external tables` in `hive` (no filters, with the same structure)

In import I want to bring:

> - New data for existing tables
> - Updated data for existing tables (using only the id column)
> - New tables created in mysql (y to create external table in hive)

Then create a `sqoop job` to do it all automatically.

(I have a `mysql` database with approximately 60 tables, and with each new client going into production, a new table is created. So I need `sqoop` to work as automatically as possible)

The first command executed to import all the tables was:

`sqoop import-all-tables 
--connect jdbc:mysql://IP/db_name 
--username user 
--password pass 
--warehouse-dir /user/hdfs/db_name 
-m 1`

Here [Scoop and support for external Hive tables](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-816) says that support was added for the creation of external tables in `hive`, but I did not find documentation or examples on the mentioned commands

> What are the best practices to work with in `sqoop` where it looks at
>   all the updates from a `mysql` database and passes to `hdfs` and `hive`?

Any ideas would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Scoop and support for external Hive tables (SQOOP-816)  is still unresolved