# Best ways to do select in hdfs?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, relational-database, sqoop

I have a hadoop environment with 1 master and 4 nodes where I am saving all the data of a mysql application with sqoop

I need to access this data saved in hadoop through the web of the application, in other words: If the user makes a record with a date before 6 months I want the application to select in hadoop data.

They are relational data, mysql. I do not have to do any great analysis.

- Is this viable?
- What's the best way to do it?
- What tool do you use?
- Is sending the data in the hdfs not feasible for this case?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you are importing data from MySQL to HDFS using sqoop.

Now you want to perform some query over this data in HDFS.

---

You can do this using **Hive**. You can perform HQL (similar to SQL) on your data.

You can import your data directly from MySQL to Hive using sqoop. Now you have table in Hive similar to MySQL. You can perform any query over it.

Sample command:

```
sqoop import \
--connect 'jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/classicmodels' \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--username root \
--password root \
--table abc \
--target-dir /user/dev/db/sqoop/temp_81323/ \
--hive-import \
--hive-table hive_abc \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--verbose
```

Check sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) for more details.

Comment: The problem is that I have to do the import of the external tables manually in hive, I currently have more than 50 tables and every day new tables are created

Comment: And how would I have to do to make the select in hive since from a web? Why command lines? Or hive have any api? I saw that there is a library for java ...

Comment: your can use  [import-all-tables](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_2) to import all tables of a databsase.

Comment: @sola.carol yes hive has java api and JDBC driver too.

Comment: But need in case I do not need external tables in hive? Sorry for my question, I'm alone in this project ... By what I researched sqoop does not matter for external tables in hive automatically... Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534490/best-practices-to-work-sqoop-hdfs-and-hive